# MVC, ADFS 2.0 and WIF 4.5 issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, wif, adfs

I am trying to query ADFS actively in an MVC 4.0 project.  We will have multiple STS's and cannot get by with my current understanding of the "passive" authentication configuration.

I **am able** to get a token back from the ADFS server, but when I try to read the token, I get a Cryptographic error message along with an inner exception of "The Data is Invalid".

*And the recommendation about the ApplicationPool is not my issue.

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(OtherStsAddress);
UserNameWSTrustBinding binding = new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
WSTrustChannelFactory factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, endpointAddress);
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = string.Concat(domain, "\\", username); 
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
factory.TrustVersion = System.ServiceModel.Security.TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
WSTrustChannel channel = (WSTrustChannel)factory.CreateChannel();
RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken(RequestTypes.Issue, KeyTypes.Symmetric);
rst.AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(YourStsAddress);    
var genericToken = channel.Issue(rst) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;                
var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;

// blowing up here
var token = handlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(genericToken.TokenXml.OuterXml)));  

var identity = handlers.ValidateToken(token).First();    
var sessionToken = new SessionSecurityToken(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(sessionToken, true);
return token;
```

The exception is as follows:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ID1073: A CryptographicException occurred when attempting to decrypt the cookie using the ProtectedData API (see inner exception for details). If you are using IIS 7.5, this could be due to the loadUserProfile setting on the Application Pool being set to false.  ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The data is invalid.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
   at System.IdentityModel.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IdentityModel.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Decode(Byte[] encoded)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ApplyTransforms(Byte[] cookie, Boolean outbound)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader, SecurityTokenResolver tokenResolver)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ReadToken(XmlReader reader)
   at Compass.SupplyChain.UI.Controllers.Registration.RegistrationController.RequestSecurityToken(String domain, String username, String password)
```

Any direction would be appreciated, even if you don't have a direct answer.  I'm not even sure what to do next.  Googling isn't even returning helpful results at this point.  Or maybe I am just braindead at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably taking the route of maximum complexity :-). What problem do you have with "passive configuration"? It should just work.

There're plenty of examples of MVC 4 / ADFS (or other STSs).

A few samples/resources to look at:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359105.aspx
- http://claimsid.codeplex.com/releases/view/68061

Comment: It's true, there's not a lot out there in the realm of WIF and simple federation. I'm trudging through a POC built on Thinktecture's Identity Server. They have some good examples showing how the handlers are configured at application startup and then automatically used when handling messages for loading the identity. I've also found figure 8 on this page helpful.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335707.aspx